# Setting up SSH tunnel through GCE

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ssh-tunnel

I'm following the instructions here
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce
to set up SSH tunnel through Compute Engine. I created a compute instance using this command:

```
gcloud compute instances create --zone us-west1-a tunnel
```

Which is fine, then I tried running the command to start an SSH tunnel on machine on local port 5000 and SSH port 22:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone us-west1-a tunnel -- -N -p 22 -D localhost:5000
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are using does not work on Windows, only Linux. The CLI gcloud launches putty.exe on Windows. Review the putty documentation on the equivalent command-line options and directly launch putty.exe instead of the CLI. For Windows, I recommend using the Windows version of ssh.exe (OpenSSH) instead.

[Installation of OpenSSH For Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with that tutorial, but was able to make it work using this command format instead:

```
gcloud compute ssh tunnel --zone=us-west1-a -- -NL 5000:localhost:5000
```